# Get poll's results and user selections from Telegram's bot API

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to know if there is a way to find user's replies to a non anonymous poll, using bot API.
I'm able to get the number of votes, but I would like to know the actual choice from a specific user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219884/get-the-final-results-particiapnts-ids-of-telegram-poll-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for non-anonymous polls you get an update when a user makes a vote. Those are the updates with `update.poll_answer`, see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update and https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pollanswer.

Because you used the corresponding tag, I'm assuming that you're using the `python-telegram-bot` library. In that case you can use the [PollAnswerHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.pollanswerhandler.html) to catch those updates. Please also have a look at the [pollbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/pollbot.py) example, which summarizes some common use cases for polls.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: This requires the bot to catch all the updates as they happen. Is there a way to get the results from a poll without having handled the previous updates? E.g., when a poll is forwarded to us.