# Get the final results (particiapnts IDs) of Telegram poll in python

Tags: python, api, telegram

I want to post and get the results (Telegram ID/username of who voted for a specific answer) of a Telegram poll using python.
I know it's possible to get update with handlers (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/pollbot.py) but it's not practical as it requires to keep running the code and bot.
I'm wondering if there is a way to call the python api once and get the results of the poll after a certain time or after stopping poll. I tried something like this using Telgram Update but it doesn't return anything!

```py
def function(update=Update):
    answers = update.poll.options
```

Comment: are you asking about anonymous or non-anonymous polls?

Comment: anonymous. I found a solution using Pyrogram.

Comment: I suggest that you provide an answer your own question, then.