# Trying to retrieve the answer of a Telegram poll

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have been able to do a poll successfully, but not able to retrieve the results (to log them in local).
I've been all day trying to get results. My lasts tries are with the # at the end, but no luck.

Here's the code I'm currently running (without token). It runs but haven't figured out how to get the answers:

```
from telegram import Update, Poll
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, PollHandler
import requests

async def poll(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    q_text="What have you done today?"
    poll_text=['train','study','show love']
    await 

def poll_handler2(update,context):          #
    option_1_text=Update.poll.options[1].text       #
    print(option_1_text)                #
    return option_1_text                #

context.bot.send_poll(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,question=q_text,options=poll_text,allows_multiple_answers=True,is_anonymous=False)

if __name__=='__main__':
    application=ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN').build()

    poll_handler=CommandHandler('poll', poll)
    application.add_handler(poll_handler)
    application.add_handler(PollHandler(poll_handler2)) #
    
    application.run_polling()
```

Any help would be more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to an answer reading and rereading the answer from a similar question of the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022098/get-polls-results-and-user-selections-from-telegrams-bot-api), with trial and error with the code from here:
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/pollbot.py

Thank you very much CallMeStag.